# set value to <li> tag and update the prop on:click $event vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to update props child to parent with on:click $event.

I passed the data and $event to parent to child, like below. 
**in parent**;

```
<v-filter
    :sortTypePrice="sortTypePrice"
    :sortTypeNewest="sortTypeNewest"
    v-on:updatePrice="sortTypePrice = $event"
    v-on:updateDate="sortTypeNewest = $event"
/>


data(){
    return {
        sortTypePrice: "",
        sortTypeNewest: "",
    }
 }

computed: {
  filterArticles(){

      let filteredStates = this.api.filter((article) => {
          return (this.keyword.length === 0 || article.address.includes(this.keyword)) 
      });

      if(this.sortTypePrice == "price") {
          filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price1 - curr.price1);
      }
      if(this.sortTypeNewest == 'created_at') {
          filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(curr.created_at) - Date.parse(prev.created_at));
      }

      return filteredStates;
  },
}
```

I got the props and set the $event update. But my @click is not working.

**in child**

```
<ul>
  <li v-model="sortPrice" @click="updatePrice" :value="price">lowest</li>
  <li v-model="sortDate" @click="updateDate" :value="created_at">newest</li>
</ul>


props:["sortTypePrice", "sortTypeNewest"],
name: "controller",
data(){
    return {
        price: "price",
        created_at: "created_at",
        sortPrice:this.sortTypePrice,
        sortDate:this.sortTypeNewest,
    };
},
methods: {
    updatePrice(e){
        this.$emit("updatePrice", e.target.value)
    },
    updateDate(e){
        this.$emit("updateDate", e.target.value)
    }
}
```

I think, I am using very wrong way to do this. if it so, what is the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set both `:value` and `v-model`. You can try

```
<ul>
  <li @click="$emit('updatePrice', 'price')" :value="price">lowest</li>
  <li @click="$emit('updateDate', 'created_at')" :value="created_at">newest</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: okay, it's worked out. Thank you!! and also don't need to use `:value=""` because already setting it inside $emit. The part I don't understand. I used it like this: `<li @click="updatePrice" :value="price">安い順</li>` but it didn't work it out... what is the difference? why $emit can't update over the `methods:{}`?

Comment: Because HTML tag `<li>` doesnt have `value` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer! but there must be a way to set attribute value to HTML tag `<li>`  like I asked in the topic... @EmīlsGulbis

Comment: If you want to set value for element like this, you should create custom component with value prop

Answer (score 0):

I find the following the best way to sync a prop between parent and child component:

in parent:

```
<!-- notice `sync` modifier -->
<child :foo.sync="val" />
```

in child:

```
<input v-model="foo_" />

props: ['foo'],
computed: {

    // create a local proxy for the `foo` prop
    foo_{
        // its value should be the value of the prop
        get(){
            return this.foo
        },

        // when we try to change it we should update the prop instead
        set(val){
            this.$emit('update:foo', val)
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the child component you can work with the `foo_` prop the same way as you would with the `foo` prop. Whenever you try to change it, it will update the `foo` prop in the parent and then sync down so that `foo_` remains equal to `foo`. For example `this.foo_ = 1` would make `foo == 1`.

This is the same pattern that is applied with the `v-model` directive. Check [.sync Modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) for better understanding.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will try this later on.